# `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression, normalize=True` does nothing

Tags: regression, python

I'm translating Andrew Ng's MATLAB code to Python in the first exercise. I have to feature normalize (we have the number of bedrooms (1-6) and Price (30000-40000), so its obvious that feature scaling is necessary here, but here is the problem:

```
regr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=1)
regr.fit(X[:,0:n], y.ravel())
regr.score(X[:,0:n],y.ravel())
0.7329450180289141
```

OK, all good. Now with normalization (notice the `normalize = True`):

```
regr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=True, copy_X=True, n_jobs=1)
regr.fit(X[:,0:n], )
regr.score(X[:,0:n],y)
0.7329450180289141
```

Same score! Am I doing something wrong here? Also when I predict

```
regr.predict(np.array([2104,3]))
```

I get the same prediction so its clearly not working.

EDIT: thanks Mathew, well a guy from github told me the same thing:

> What makes you think it's not working? If you have a well-posed problem (n_samples >> n_features) it's totally expected.

I thought since feature 2 is 10e+4 bigger than feature 1, feature scaling should improve the score a lot.  This is weird, also `fit_intercept` should be set to `False` if you're doing feature scaling.

Comment: Why do you think you should get a different answer?  It will help for you to lay out carefully why you believe that should be the case.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: If `normalize=True` does what it looks like, it is merely changing the units of measurement of the variables.  Since that's an affine change, then any linear regression that includes a constant will be unaffected in principle.  (In practice, there are extreme situations where failure to normalize can create numerical instability in the solution.)